# Zero out everything except for max in Custom Keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am currently in the process of creating a custom keras layer with no trainable parameters

The input to this layer is of shape (batch size, sequence length, features). This is essentially the same as the input to a 1D global max pooling layer.

What I am trying to do with this custom layer, is to perform a 1D global max pooling without reducing the dimensionality. (Just want to zero out the non-max entries for each feature)
On top of this, I want the output to have one extra dimension such that it can then be passed to a 2D convolutional layer.

So the output of this Layer should be of shape (batch size, sequence length, features, 1)
Where a 1D global max pooling was performed by zeroing out everything that is not the max

Here is the skeleton of the Layer

```py
class GlobalMaxPoolZeroOutNonMax(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GlobalMaxPoolZeroOutNonMax, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=3)
        self.data_format = K.normalize_data_format('channels_last')

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2], 1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        # THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP to zero out the non max and add a dimension
        raise NotImplemented

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'data_format': self.data_format}
        base_config = super(GlobalMaxPoolZeroOutNonMax, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use subclassing. You can achieve this with the following. One thing you have to keep in mind is that this will keep **all** max values (not just a single max value - But it is highly unlikely to have two max values in a real neural network layer).

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import tensorflow as tf
width = 20
n_channels = 3
inp = layers.Input(shape=(width, n_channels))
out = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(tf.cast(tf.equal(x, tf.reduce_max(x)), tf.float32)*x,axis=-1))(inp)

model = models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
model.summary()
```

Testing

```
x = np.zeros(shape=(10, width, n_channels))
x[0, 2, 2] = 2.0

y = model.predict(x)
print(y.shape)
print(y)
```

Result

```
(10, 20, 3, 1)

[[[[0.]
   [0.]
   [0.]]

  [[0.]
   [0.]
   [0.]]

  [[0.]
   [0.]
   [2.]]

  [[0.]
   [0.]
   [0.]]

  ...

  [[0.]
   [0.]
   [0.]]]]
```